# Delete object everyday in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

i'm trying to delete folders(objects) in the S3 bucket everyday (with lifecycle rule). I have this scenario :
TestBucket -> connect/ -> test/ -> 2023/ -> 12/ -> 01/, 02/, 03/ etc.

I want to delete only 01, 02 objects, how can i specify that? I tried to put in the prefix connect/test/2023/12/ but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered S3's lifecycle rules for this?

Comment: This is what i'm doing. But my rule doesn't delete the object that i put in the prefix like i described

Comment: Did you wait a few hours for the lifecycle rules to process? They're not instant.

Comment: I waited 2 days, my rule run after 1. I think it's something about limiting the scope with filters.

Comment: i put in the prefix connect/test/2023/12/ because i want to delete objectes inside the "12/" folder